# How to make readable a line plot using a DataFrame with a large number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a 1,000,000 x 2 DataFrame object consisting of data I'm trying to understand visually.  Its basically a simulation of 1,000,000 events where a packet traveling along a network is either queued or dropped depending on the buffer's size.  So, the two column values are Packets in Queue and Packets Dropped.

I'm trying to make a line plot using Python, Matplotlib and Jupyter Notebooks that has the ID of the event on the x-axis and the number of packets in the queue at a specific ID point on the y-axis. There should be two lines, the first representing the number of packets in the queue and the second representing the number of packets dropped.  However, given that there are over 1,000,000 simulations, the graph isn't intelligible. The values are too squished together. Is it possible to make a readable graph with 1,000,000 event instances or do I need to dramatically trim the number of events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a million data points it will require a lot of effort and zooming in to see them in fine detail. [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/) has some nice tools for zooming in and out of plots as well as sliding your data window along the x-axis.

If you're okay with some averaging, you can plot a moving average and get close to a hundred thousand points. You can stack two subplots on each other to see both columns of data in reasonable detail. You can of course average them more, but you lose the ability to see fine details.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def moving_avg(x, N=30):
    return np.convolve(x, np.ones((N,))/N, mode='valid')

plt.figure(figsize = (16,12))

plt.subplot(3,1,1)
x = np.random.random(1000)
plt.plot(x, linewidth = 1, alpha = 0.5, label = 'linewidth = 1')
plt.plot(moving_avg(x, 10), 'C0', label = 'moving average, N = 10')
plt.xlim(0,len(x))
plt.legend(loc=2)

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
x = np.random.random(10000)
plt.plot(x, linewidth = 0.2, alpha = 0.5, label = 'linewidth = 0.2')
plt.plot(moving_avg(x, 100), 'C0', label = 'moving average, N = 100')
plt.xlim(0,len(x))
plt.legend(loc=2)

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
x = np.random.random(100000)
plt.plot(x, linewidth = 0.05, alpha = 0.5, label = 'linewidth = 0.05')
plt.plot(moving_avg(x, 500), 'C0', label = 'moving average, N = 500')
plt.xlim(0,len(x))
plt.legend(loc=2)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try histogram

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import hist
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.random.rand(1000000)
hist(df.index, weights=df.x, bins=1000)
plt.show()
```

## Method 2 line plots

```
df['x'] = np.random.rand(1000000)
df['y'] = np.random.rand(1000000)
w = 1000
v1 = df['x'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=w).sum()[[i*w for i in range(1, int(len(df)/w))]]/w
v2 = df['y'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=w).sum()[[i*w for i in range(1, int(len(df)/w))]]/w
plt.plot(np.arange(len(v1)),v1, c='b')
plt.plot(np.arange(len(v1)),v2, c='r')
plt.show()
```

We are calculating the mean of w=1000 points i.e averaging w values together and plotting them.

Looks like below when 1000000 points are bucked at every 1000 interval

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should say it needs to be a line plot with two lines, the first being the number of packets in the queue and the second being the number of packets dropped.